# Function that returns two matrices in a convenient way

Tags: function, julia

I would like to create a function in Julia that returns two matrices. One way to do that is as follows:

```
function AB(n,m)
    A = rand(n,n)
    B = rand(m,m)
    return (A = A, B = B)
end
```

The output looks like this:

```
julia> AB(2,3)                                                                   
(A = [0.7001462182920173 0.5485248069467998; 0.8559801029748708 0.8023848206563642], B = [0.7970654693626167 0.08666821253389378 0.45550050243098306; 0.5436826530244554 0.9204593389763813 0.9270606176586167; 0.7055633627200892 0.3702008285594489 0.670758477684624])
```

The output is not particularly convenient. What I would like to have is something similar to what the function `qr()` from `LinearAlgebra` returns. For example:

```
julia> qr(rand(3,3))                                                             
LinearAlgebra.QRCompactWY{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}
Q factor:
3×3 LinearAlgebra.QRCompactWYQ{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}:
 -0.789051  -0.570416   -0.228089
 -0.213035  -0.0941769   0.972495
 -0.576207   0.815939   -0.0472084
R factor:
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.929496  -0.563585  -0.787584
  0.0        0.377304  -0.505203
  0.0        0.0       -0.01765
```

This output is very useful to get at least some idea how these matrices look like.

How can I create a function that returns the matrices like the function `qr()` from `LinearAlgebra`?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You will need to define your own `display` method. I present here an abstract approach so you can comfortably reuse it.

We start with a decorator supertype - all structs having this supertype will be nicely displayed.

```
abstract type Pretty end
```

And here is the actual implementation:

```
function Base.display(x::Pretty)
    for f in fieldnames(typeof(x))
         print(f," is a ")
         display(getfield(x,f))
    end
 end
```

Let us now see it. You just define any `struct`, e.g.:

```
struct S{T}  <: Pretty
    a::Matrix{T}
    b::Matrix{T}
end
```

And now you have what you need e.g.:

```
julia> S(rand(2,3), rand(3,2))
a is a 2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.40661   0.753072   0.708016
 0.371099  0.0948791  0.538046
b is a 3×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.670715  0.457208
 0.353189  0.0248713
 0.455794  0.136496
```

Comment: One nit: the docstring for `display` explains that you should overload `show` and not `display`. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-custom-pretty-printing.